# How do I force sync the time on Windows Workstation or Server?

Tags: windows, time

What is the command to sync a Windows workstation or server to its configured time source?

Comment: More about W32tm can be found here... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx

Comment: I created a bug ticket for this. Windows fails to sync with time server upon startup, or resume from sleep or hibernation. Windows URI: `feedback-hub:?contextid=58&feedbackid=f15278d4-b20d-4a9a-9693-cdf8fbaaa669&form=1&src=1` <- Place into Windows Run dialogue if you have feedback-hub installed from the windows store

Answer (score 122, accepted):

As Kyle said `w32tm /resync` is the modern way to do this. See this [Link to Microsoft Knowledgebase (KB 307897)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307897/how-to-synchronize-the-time-with-the-windows-time-service-in-windows-x) for more information on the w32tm command.

There is also `net time` which is an older version but perhaps easier.

Comment: `w32tm /resync` says "The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big." as my CMOS battery is dead and my computer clock resets on every boot at 1/1/2000 12:00 AM. Any help?

Comment: Found solution as per http://blog.bruteforcetech.com/archives/911 , do not forget to restart W32Time service `net stop W32Time` then retry `w32tm /resync`

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @StijnSanders Thanks, found the original article again and fixed

Comment: Thanks, but I was refering to the bruteforcetech.com link.

Comment: @NeverQuit, what is the solution?  The solution in your comment is a broken link.

Comment: @NeverQuit: For me, the second command fails if W32Time is not running. So your sequence of commands doesn't work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and the others, if you get the "time change was too big" error, use `w32tm /resync /force`. But if you don't have the service started, run `net start w32time`. Both from an elevated prompt.

Comment: To solve 'time change was too big' change registry entries MaxNegPhaseCorrection and MaxPosPhaseCorrection in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config to maximum (ffffffff)

Comment: In Windows server 2016, there is no `/force` for `w32tm`

Comment: @Never Quit : after w32tm service i stopped, then w32time /resync prints error because service is not working.

Comment: @NeverQuit / @-StijnSanders / @-JaredThirsk - Here is an archive of the bruteforcetech article: [Windows Time Service does not sync, even after all settings verified | BFTech Impressions](http://web.archive.org/web/20151029015046/http://blog.bruteforcetech.com/archives/911). And, there is this article which is referred to in the bruteforcetech article: [Make Windows synchronize time more often](https://www.pretentiousname.com/timesync/).

Comment: @StijnSanders - See my comment above.

Comment: @JaredThirsk - See my comment above.

Answer (score 61):

For those that still asking this question.

1. To update, use the command below (2008 and 2012 server compatible)

   ```
   w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"ntp_server" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
   ```

change the ntp_server with your source

2. Restart the time service

   ```
   net stop w32time
   net start w32time
   ```
3. Resync the time

   ```
   w32tm /resync
   ```
4. Verify your sync status

   ```
   w32tm /query /status
   ```

Commands above should be fine if your sources are working correctly and/or your connection is OK (firewall or Microsoft Forefront can be an issue also). The commands below can help with troubleshooting

To list out peers

```
w32tm /query /peers
```

To list out NTP Sources:

```
w32tm /query /source
```

Comment: As a note, this works for Windows 10 Professional without the "/update" flag as that is invalid.

Comment: For troubleshooting, it's often useful to test the connection to a specific server: `w32tm /monitor /computers:time.windows.com`

Answer (score 25):

You can use the following command:

`w32tm /resync`

Answer (score 25):

You can use:

```
w32tm /resync
```

Additionally, using `w32tm /resync /rediscover` will also ["force redetection of network resourced before resynchronization."](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/time_w32tm.mspx?mfr=true)

Or using:

```
net time /set
```

Will prompt you to set the time to the DC. (Works for older versions of Windows)

Comment: For some reason `w32tm /resync` didn't work for me but `net time /SET /Y` did. I used `/Y` for `net time` because it apparently doesn't read stdin properly when going through sshd from cygwin.

Comment: When running `w32tm /resync` I got the message `The computer did not resync because no time data was available.` even after a service restart but `net time /SET` worked properly for me.

Answer (score 7):

Powershell one liner if ntp server is configured:

`gsv w32time | sasv; w32tm /resync /force`

You can put this .bat file in the startup if you CMOS batery failed so it can resync upon OS start:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -Command 'gsv w32time | sasv; w32tm /resync /force'
```

Comment: `/force` is not a documented command-line option for `w32tm /resync`.

Answer (score 7):

- change your time server

```perl
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:manual /update
```

- fore update time

```perl
w32tm /resync /force
```

Answer (score 5):

OS: MS Windows 7

**All above ideas have been tried but did not help. The original problem still exists: "*The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big.*"**

Solution is found in the registry:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\w32time\Config**

- change this if the local time is in a hurry (e.g. 31-Dec-2050):
  MaxNegPhaseCorrection
- change this if the local time is delayed (e.g.
  1-Jan-1980): MaxPosPhaseCorrection
- The default values are 0xD2F0 (i.e. 54000 sec. = 15 hours)

(use Google for more details)

I use this simple `win_clock_sync.bat` file from Start Menu StartUp:

```
echo off
echo Sync computer time from internet
echo.
echo Back-up registry w32time\Config
reg export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\w32time\Config exported_w32time.reg /y
rem changing the registry keys temporarly:
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\w32time\Config /v MaxNegPhaseCorrection /d 0xFFFFFFFF /t REG_DWORD /f
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\w32time\Config /v MaxPosPhaseCorrection /d 0xFFFFFFFF /t REG_DWORD /f
echo.
echo w32tm /config /update
w32tm /config /update
echo.
echo w32tm /resync /rediscover 
w32tm /resync /rediscover 
echo.
echo Restore registry w32time\Config
reg import exported_w32time.reg
```

Enjoy! :-)

Comment: Your answer could use an explanation of the function of the `MaxNegPhaseCorrection` and `MaxPosPhaseCorrection` values instead of suggesting that they should be blindly disabled. That's what this script does by setting their data to **0xFFFFFFFF**.

Comment: You cannot ignore the mentioned error message "The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big." without changing the data in the MaxNegPhaseCorrection and MaxPosPhaseCorrection values. Or, did YOU find any working solution to the original problem?? And why are you writing "blindly"? If you would take a short time to read through then you could see the exporting and importing the original data of these values, what is a bit far from doing something "blindly".

Comment: You should have this script change the values to disabled, force an update, and then change them back to recommended values.

Comment: Twisty has valid points that do not really focus on the issue raised by NeverQuit... but then Akos has not clearly explained why the script is an appropriate solution for NeverQuit. In essence, the Registry values MaxNegPhaseCorrection and MaxPosPhaseCorrection exist to stop the W32Time service from applying dramatic changes to current time [in circumstances such as an external time source going badly awry] However, if some issue occurs that leads to a PDCe drifting rapidly from a reliable time source, then the correction controls will prevent w32tm fixing the big drift.
In this situation:::
b

Comment: @Akos Downvote retracted based on your pointing out that your script indeed does revert the changes to the `MaxNegPhaseCorrection` and `MaxPosPhaseCorrection` values. I still encourage including an explanation of what these two settings do as they're a key feature of your answer and it's important that an admin be aware that should they put these settings in place permanently they would configure their system to accept any time change, no matter how large, which could break Kerberos and other important network services.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I think within the context of this question (dead CMOS battery), it's a fairly safe "hack". You are right, the max positive and negative delta (which is kinda obvious from the names of the variables) are there for a good reason, and are part of the NTP protocol, however, when you have a dead CMOS battery and a system clock that boots up to ctime 0 (or something equally useless) on every boot, I think this is an appropriate temporary measure until the machine is retired or its CMOS battery is replaced.

Comment: It works on XP too if you remove confimation switch `/y`. Tested. Thanks.

Comment: `MaxNegPhaseCorrection` and `MaxPosPhaseCorrection` are both set to `ffffffff` and I still get the ` the required time change was too big` message.  This is Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my research, I bookmarked this:

0. If Hyper-v host server is a part of the same domain, disable time sync for PDC guest vm
1. On PDC(or any single workstation), update from quoted internal DNS or ip untrusted address(0x8):

   W32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"192.168.0.254,0x8" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update

   Powershell Restart-Service w32time

   W32tm /resync /nowait
2. on dc that is not PDC:

   w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update

   W32tm /resync /rediscover
3. On servers and other stations for update time only, not config:

   W32tm /resync /nowait
4. Check that time is really updating(difference ):

   w32tm /stripchart /computer:192.168.0.254 /samples:15 /dataonly
5. if time service broken or failed and need reset:

   Powershell Stop-service w32time
   W32tm /unregister
   Timeout 30
   W32tm /register
   Powershell Start-service w32time

Note: NTP port is 123 UDP and should give the same output on any healthy computer

```
Powershell Get-NetUDPEndpoint -LocalPort 123


LocalAddress                             LocalPort
------------                             ---------
::                                       123
0.0.0.0                                  123
```

Other commands
w32tm /query /status
w32tm /query /peers
w32tm /query /configuration

Best practice from ms: [Time Sync best practices](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/043b1ebe-e7bc-40ca-91e0-174a6854808e/time-sync-best-practices)

Answer (score 2):

> The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big.

powershell> Set-Date "02/01/2023 4:20:00 PM"

Check your phone or VCR for current approximate time, Windows will be mad if the drift is +/- 5 minutes, so you have some wiggle room.

Comment: My experience in Windows 10 is that `w32tm /resync` complains if the date set is more than 1 minute off.

Answer (score 1):

```
net start w32time
w32tm /resync
```

[According to Riot Games](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202536660-Issues-with-the-League-of-Legends-Store-PvP-Net-#wq1)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Win10 image that I can restore to a snapshot where this error message is always reproducible: `"The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big."`

I have tried to script a solution to this problem with no avail:

```
reg import nettime.reg # updates MaxPosPhaseOffset and MaxNegPhaseOffset

net start w32time
w32tm.exe /config /manualpeerlist:"pool.ntp.org",0x8 /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:no /update  
w32tm.exe /query /configuration
w32tm.exe /resync /rediscover
w32tm.exe /resync /force
```

Neither the `/reliable:no` nor the `MaxPosPhaseCorrection` settings, nor any other commands indicated here worked immediately in a reproducible way.

After updating the registry, starting the service, updating the configuration and again restarting the service I still had to wait many minutes before I `w32tm /resync /rediscover` would succeed.

The time syncronization does succeed eventually, just not in a timely and reliable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Almost none of the solutions (except @Akos) work if the host is an Windows Server 2016 Active Directory Domain Controller (ADDC), as it treats itself as a "reliable" source that cannot make big time change.

`w32tm /resync /force` does not work, because the `/force` does not appear in server 2016.

`net time /SET /Y` does not work either, because it would have asked:

> Do you want to set the local computer's time to match the time at
>   `\AD.example.net`? (Y/N) [Y]

Of course, it won't work if you are on `AD.example.net`, `/Y` just hides the question.

The steps work for me using PowerShell:

1. Set w32time service as *unreliable*:

```
w32tm /config /reliable:no /syncfromflags:manual /update
```

Option `/syncfromflags:manual` means sync with NTP listed in peer list (i.e. external NTP),  `/update` for notifying the time service the configuration have changed.

2. Restart the w32time

```
Stop-Service w32time
Start-Service w32time
```

3. Sync

```
w32tm /resync
```

This should work.

4. If you DO need ADDC as a reliable time source, make it reliable again:

```
w32tm /config /reliable:yes /update
Stop-Service w32time
Start-Service w32time
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me because "**The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big.**", I ended up using node with [ntp-client](https://github.com/moonpyk/node-ntp-client) to set the approximated current time and then be able to resync

.bat file

```
::time service needs to be started before changing time
net start W32Time
node.exe time_set.js
w32tm /resync
pause
```

time_set.js

```javascript
const ntp_server = 'localhost'; //replace with your ntp server address
const ntp_port = 123; //replace with your ntp server port

const ntp_client = require('ntp-client');
const {exec} = require('child_process');

//get ntp time
ntp_client.getNetworkTime(ntp_server, ntp_port, (err, ntp_date) => {
  //exit with error code
  if (err) { process.exit(1); }
  //go back to 23:59:30 if close to midnight
  if (ntp_date.getHours() === 23 && ntp_date.getMinutes() === 59 && ntp_date.getSeconds() > 30) {
    ntp_date.setSeconds(30);
  }
  //set date
  exec(`date ${ntp_date.toLocaleDateString()}`, {shell: true});
  //set time
  exec(`time ${ntp_date.toLocaleTimeString()}`, {shell: true});
});
```

Notes:

- This has to be run as administrator
- This seems to work with different default regional formats. If you are setting custom date and time formats, set them after synchronizing time.
- If you need custom date and time formats support you might need to read the formats from the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` (most likely values `sShortDate` and `sTimeFormat`) and then manually format the date or use a tool like [date-and-time](https://github.com/knowledgecode/date-and-time)

Answer (score -1):

Try one-line command. Works all the time.

```
w32tm /unregister && w32tm /register && net stop w32time && net start w32time && w32tm /resync
```

Comment: I had to wait about 10 minutes between the first and second commands because of a `The following error occurred: The specified service has been marked for deletion. (0x80070430)` error. Then the next 3 commands worked, but the `w32tm /resync` command results in `The computer did not resync because no time data was available.`

Comment: Unregistering the service didn't work for me, it just left me with `The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.`.  I had to go into `services.msc` and change `Windows Time` from `disabled` to `automatic` which also happened to fix my issue.